# View engine can't find my view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewengine

I am getting the following error when trying to return a ViewResult from a post action:

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: 
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml 
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Home/Home.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Home.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
>   ~/Views/Home/Home.master
>   ~/Views/Shared/Home.master
>   ~/Views/Home/Home.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Home.vbhtml

My view is definitely recognised because it works on the GET action.

The code that returns the ViewResult in the POST action is:

```
return View("Index", "Home", Model);
```

[Here is the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxQn2.png).

Can anybody suggest why this would not be working?

A little more context:
    The get action displays the view fine. The post action is actually to a different url but returns the same view. It's the post action that's causing the problem. Both GET and POST actions are on the same controller `HomeController`.

Here's the (stripped down) controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new LoginModelBase());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UsernameLoginModel Model)
    {
        ...
        return View("Index", "Home", Model);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post some more code .....

Comment: Are both urls go to the same path?

Comment: Do you use RazorGenerator in your project?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Razor generator is used by a referenced project. The _layout is coming from said project. This view is not using razor generator.

Comment: @AmiramKorach. GET url is http://mydomain.com/ or http://mydomain.com/Home/Index. POST url is http://mydomain.com/Home/Login

Comment: @ankur. I've added the relevant parts of the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just realised what it is!. I'm using the wrong overload of the `View(...)` method.

It should be:

```
View("Index", Model);
```

Comment: Yes, "Home" was referring to a Master, not a Controller.